# Get longitude and latitude for the corners of a geohash

Tags: flutter, geohashing

How can I get the longitude and latitude of the four corners of a geohash?
Preferrably in Flutter.

Comment: Try this package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_geo_hash)

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries, such as:

- [dart_geohash](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_geohash)
- [GeoFlutterFire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) (if you plan to use it with Firestore)

As indicated in the *dart_geohash* docs:

```dart
// Create a simple geohash from a given string
final GeoHash myHash = GeoHash("9yf0zhhtj");


myHash.longitude();
myHash.latitude(decimalAccuracy: 4);
```

Comment: I think that will just give me the center point of the hash? Or is it one of the corners?